# Better way to customize tables in Power App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have a table to be customized in Power App to use in SharePoint site. The table look like this:

[image: Table view]

This table should be customizable for users to add new rows or update already available data in the table. I think Data table in Power App is read only. So, I tried to use Vertical gallery to display items of the table. But gallery shows items row by row. I want the items to be displayed in column by column because that's what suits the table. When a user clicks on Goals rectangle in the gallery, it should display goals for the user.

How can I achieve this? How to show the items in table column wise in a vertical gallery? Suggestions please.